# Match a vector element to a character in R?

Tags: r

so basically what Im trying to figure out is - is there a way to match a character to a numerical vector element. The examples below will hopefully explain what I mean.

If I have some numerical vectors:

```
numVec <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
numVec_2 <- c(1,1,1,2,3,3,4,5,5,5,6,6,7,8,8,9)
```

And I have a character vector:

```
words <- c("The", "man", "went", "to", "the", "store", "and", "bought", "bread")
```

Im trying to match the word to the corresponding number in the numerical vector... The result im trying to achieve would look something like this for `numVec`:

```
[1] "The"    "man"    "went"   "to"     "the"    "store"  "and"    "bought" "bread"
```

And the result for `numVec_2` would look like this:

```
[1] "The" "The" "The" "man" "went" "went" "to" "the" "the" "the" "store" "store" "and" "bought" "bought" "bread"
```

Im kind of stumped on this one... Any suggestion as to how I would do this?

Comment: Just do `words[numVec_2]`

Comment: A more general solution would be `map <- setNames(words, numVec); map[numVec_2]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an indexing task as @markus said:

```
words[numVec]

[1] "The"    "man"    "went"   "to"     "the"    "store"  "and"    "bought" "bread" 

words[numVec_2]

[1] "The"    "The"    "The"    "man"    "went"   "went"   "to"     "the"    "the"    "the"    "store" 
[12] "store"  "and"    "bought" "bought" "bread"
```

Comment: @Onyambu - Unless it's a duplicate or just a simple typo it doesn't really matter how simple it is.  So if you disagree it should be open then find an appropriate duplicate and propose to close it.

Comment: @Dason I think it would be more appropriate to invite markus to post their comment as answer